# How can I create unencrypted addresses?

Tags: tezos-client

In my alphanet tezos-client, `tezos-client gen keys <address>` creates an unencrypted address, and requires the `--encrypted` flag to create an encrypted address.

But in the mainnet tezos-client, running `tezos-client gen keys <address>` asks for a new password and creates an encrypted address.

How can I create unencrypted addresses via in the mainnet tezos-client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On mainnet, here is how to do it:

1. start by creating the key with a non-existent node (here `xxx` does not exist !):

```
tezos-client -A xxx gen keys for_stackexchange
```

It will display some error messages and say nothing more. In fact, the key was created.

2. call it again:

```
tezos-client -A xxx gen keys for_stackexchange
Error:
  The secret_key alias for_stackexchange already exists.
    The current value is unencrypted:edsk43pBvh7zPgiGWSG3XSHybCqdQV7XRosqcGPLA9TDBc5ens7oP4.
```

3. display the associated address:

```
tezos-client show address for_stackexchange -S                 
Warning:
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/metadata
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Connection refused"

Hash: tz1Rpm5To3JT8vpqbt681EMuxEaM4tL2MvRi
Public Key: edpkvPpcAmrCFUiwBPZ4SGEsDXQstVmLHJoXKQURE2ANXem7zQH2e9
Secret Key: unencrypted:edsk43pBvh7zPgiGWSG3XSHybCqdQV7XRosqcGPLA9TDBc5ens7oP4
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The "xxx" what does that stand for?

Comment: @Vindberg You can use it as is, `xxx`. It's a placeholder for the IP of a non existent node